# How to delete a character using Ascii in java?

Tags: java, string, ascii

Suppose i have,

```
String name="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Now, I'd like to remove `"b"` and `"j"` character from declared `name`. Is that possible using Ascii.

Here, Values of `b=98` and `j=106`..

How to do it in JAva? Is there any function that i can use in Java for `Ascii`?? Please help

**Help would be appreciated!!**

**EDITED**

I know here i could remove using `deleteCharAt(values)`. But I'd like to do it using `Ascii` functions where i could simply type number and that's it..

Comment: First try how you can find which char is assigned to your ascicode, then find where there are those characters in the string. Then generate another string without these characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible using Ascii.

No. Java uses Unicode, not ASCII.

However, it just happens that the code points defined by Unicode for "Latin", non accentuated letters [match those of ASCII](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/list.htm).

Here is how you can do it:

```
inputString.replace(new String(Character.toChars(98)), "")
    .replace(etc etc)
```

Comment: This is much better than mine was. Well you learn something new every day. :)

Comment: Your answer is `Correct`.. i'd accept it after 5 minutes

Comment: How about `Character.toString((char)98)` instead of creating a character array and then creating a new string object?

Comment: @RealSkeptic sure, my solution is not ideal, but it has the advantage of being compatible with all code points, including the ones not in the BMP ;)

Comment: @fge You have a point. However, since the OP was talking about ASCII, I think we can assume all code points are single-char.